# Duplicate project folders while uploading project to GitHub

Tags: android, git, github, duplicates, directory

I have an android project that the link to it's respository is the following:

https://github.com/alonsd/braintest-game

As you can see, the project is built out of a client android side and server java side. The problem is that the android part has been duplicated for some reason, but not actually duplicated - if you attempt to download/clone my project you will get only one folder, containing the client side android project.

I really have no clue why this issue happened, I can only assume it may have something to do with nested .git files messing around my project?

I am willing to provide any additional code or information but I do no know as for now what more I should provide.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+duplicate+folder

Comment: thank you very much, found the answer.